# HTML5 canvas following mouse effect jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm searching the web for quite sometime for the name of this effect... I've seen it on many sites but can't find a guide or a name to look for it and learn how to do it.

The effect I'm talking about is in this website header:
http://diogodantas.com/demo/elegant-index#0

Comment: Note that you can look at the page source of sites.

Comment: In the web site header? Are you referring to the hovering effect, the menu drop down, what are we looking for here?

Comment: When you hover the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this. i just ctrl + c,v.

```
(function() {

    var width, height, largeHeader, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;

    // Main
    initHeader();
    initAnimation();
    addListeners();

    function initHeader() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        target = {x: width/2, y: height/2};

        largeHeader = document.getElementById('large-header');
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';

        canvas = document.getElementById('demo-canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // create points
        points = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < width; x = x + width/20) {
            for(var y = 0; y < height; y = y + height/20) {
                var px = x + Math.random()*width/20;
                var py = y + Math.random()*height/20;
                var p = {x: px, originX: px, y: py, originY: py };
                points.push(p);
            }
        }

        // for each point find the 5 closest points
        for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            var closest = [];
            var p1 = points[i];
            for(var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
                var p2 = points[j]
                if(!(p1 == p2)) {
                    var placed = false;
                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(closest[k] == undefined) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for(var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
                        if(!placed) {
                            if(getDistance(p1, p2) < getDistance(p1, closest[k])) {
                                closest[k] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            p1.closest = closest;
        }

        // assign a circle to each point
        for(var i in points) {
            var c = new Circle(points[i], 2+Math.random()*2, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)');
            points[i].circle = c;
        }
    }

    // Event handling
    function addListeners() {
        if(!('ontouchstart' in window)) {
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
        }
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollCheck);
        window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
    }

    function mouseMove(e) {
        var posx = posy = 0;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        target.x = posx;
        target.y = posy;
    }

    function scrollCheck() {
        if(document.body.scrollTop > height) animateHeader = false;
        else animateHeader = true;
    }

    function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        largeHeader.style.height = height+'px';
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }

    // animation
    function initAnimation() {
        animate();
        for(var i in points) {
            shiftPoint(points[i]);
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        if(animateHeader) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
            for(var i in points) {
                // detect points in range
                if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 4000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.3;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.6;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 20000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.1;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.3;
                } else if(Math.abs(getDistance(target, points[i])) < 40000) {
                    points[i].active = 0.02;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0.1;
                } else {
                    points[i].active = 0;
                    points[i].circle.active = 0;
                }

                drawLines(points[i]);
                points[i].circle.draw();
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    function shiftPoint(p) {
        TweenLite.to(p, 1+1*Math.random(), {x:p.originX-50+Math.random()*100,
            y: p.originY-50+Math.random()*100, ease:Circ.easeInOut,
            onComplete: function() {
                shiftPoint(p);
            }});
    }

    // Canvas manipulation
    function drawLines(p) {
        if(!p.active) return;
        for(var i in p.closest) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
            ctx.lineTo(p.closest[i].x, p.closest[i].y);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ p.active+')';
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function Circle(pos,rad,color) {
        var _this = this;

        // constructor
        (function() {
            _this.pos = pos || null;
            _this.radius = rad || null;
            _this.color = color || null;
        })();

        this.draw = function() {
            if(!_this.active) return;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(_this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(156,217,249,'+ _this.active+')';
            ctx.fill();
        };
    }

    // Util
    function getDistance(p1, p2) {
        return Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2);
    }

})();
```

Comment: Yes, thats it. The effect itself, does it have a name?

Comment: it just some canvas demo. the file name was demo.js.
Btw if you want to know web page resource. just use developer mode your browser. almost hit the F12 key.

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot find a name but here is a link
https://codepen.io/thetwistedtaste/pen/GgrWLp

```js
/*
 *
 * TERMS OF USE - 
 * 
 * Open source under the BSD License. 
 * 
 * Copyright © 2001 Robert Penner
 * All rights reserved.
 * 
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without modification, 
 * are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
 * 
 * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this list of 
 * conditions and the following disclaimer.
 * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list 
 * of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials 
 * provided with the distribution.
 * 
 * Neither the name of the author nor the names of contributors may be used to endorse 
 * or promote products derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
 * 
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" AND ANY 
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 *  COPYRIGHT OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 *  EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE
 *  GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED 
 * AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 *  NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED 
 * OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
 *
 */
// http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
// http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating

// requestAnimationFrame polyfill by Erik Möller. fixes from Paul Irish and Tino Zijdel

// MIT license

(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
                timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}());

$( function() {

    var width, height, canvas, ctx, points, target, animateHeader = true;

    // Main
    initHeader();
    initAnimation();
    addListeners();

    function initHeader() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        target = {
            x: width / 2,
            y: height / 3
        };

        canvas = document.getElementById( 'spiders' );
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );

        // create points
        points = [];
        for ( var x = 0; x < width; x = x + width / 20 ) {
            for ( var y = 0; y < height; y = y + height / 20 ) {
                var px = x + Math.random() * width / 20;
                var py = y + Math.random() * height / 20;
                var p = {
                    x: px,
                    originX: px,
                    y: py,
                    originY: py
                };
                points.push( p );
            }
        }

        // for each point find the 5 closest points
        for ( var i = 0; i < points.length; i++ ) {
            var closest = [];
            var p1 = points[ i ];
            for ( var j = 0; j < points.length; j++ ) {
                var p2 = points[ j ]
                if ( !( p1 == p2 ) ) {
                    var placed = false;
                    for ( var k = 0; k < 5; k++ ) {
                        if ( !placed ) {
                            if ( closest[ k ] == undefined ) {
                                closest[ k ] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    for ( var k = 0; k < 5; k++ ) {
                        if ( !placed ) {
                            if ( getDistance( p1, p2 ) < getDistance( p1, closest[ k ] ) ) {
                                closest[ k ] = p2;
                                placed = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            p1.closest = closest;
        }

        // assign a circle to each point
        for ( var i in points ) {
            var c = new Circle( points[ i ], 2 + Math.random() * 2, 'rgba(255,255,255,0.3)' );
            points[ i ].circle = c;
        }
    }

    // Event handling
    function addListeners() {
        if ( !( 'ontouchstart' in window ) ) {
            window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', mouseMove );
        }
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', scrollCheck );
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', resize );
    }

    function mouseMove( e ) {
        var posx = posy = 0;
        if ( e.pageX || e.pageY ) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        } else if ( e.clientX || e.clientY ) {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        target.x = posx;
        target.y = posy;
    }

    function scrollCheck() {
        if ( document.body.scrollTop > height ) animateHeader = false;
        else animateHeader = true;
    }

    function resize() {
        width = window.innerWidth;
        height = window.innerHeight;
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
    }

    // animation
    function initAnimation() {
        animate();
        for ( var i in points ) {
            shiftPoint( points[ i ] );
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        if ( animateHeader ) {
            ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, width, height );
            for ( var i in points ) {
                // detect points in range
                if ( Math.abs( getDistance( target, points[ i ] ) ) < 2000 ) {
                    points[ i ].active = 0.2;
                    points[ i ].circle.active = 0.5;
                } else if ( Math.abs( getDistance( target, points[ i ] ) ) < 20000 ) {
                    points[ i ].active = 0.1;
                    points[ i ].circle.active = 0.3;
                } else if ( Math.abs( getDistance( target, points[ i ] ) ) < 70000 ) {
                    points[ i ].active = 0.02;
                    points[ i ].circle.active = 0.09;
                } else if ( Math.abs( getDistance( target, points[ i ] ) ) < 140000 ) {
                    points[ i ].active = 0;
                    points[ i ].circle.active = 0.02;
                } else {
                    points[ i ].active = 0;
                    points[ i ].circle.active = 0;
                }

                drawLines( points[ i ] );
                points[ i ].circle.draw();
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    }

    function shiftPoint( p ) {
        TweenLite.to( p, 1 + 1 * Math.random(), {
            x: p.originX - 50 + Math.random() * 100,
            y: p.originY - 50 + Math.random() * 100,
            onComplete: function() {
                shiftPoint( p );
            }
        } );
    }

    // Canvas manipulation
    function drawLines( p ) {
        if ( !p.active ) return;
        for ( var i in p.closest ) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo( p.x, p.y );
            ctx.lineTo( p.closest[ i ].x, p.closest[ i ].y );
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + p.active + ')';
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }

    function Circle( pos, rad, color ) {
        var _this = this;

        // constructor
        ( function() {
            _this.pos = pos || null;
            _this.radius = rad || null;
            _this.color = color || null;
        } )();

        this.draw = function() {
            if ( !_this.active ) return;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc( _this.pos.x, _this.pos.y, _this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false );
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + _this.active + ')';
            ctx.fill();
        };
    }

    // Util
    function getDistance( p1, p2 ) {
        return Math.pow( p1.x - p2.x, 2 ) + Math.pow( p1.y - p2.y, 2 );
    }

} );
```

```css
body {}
i {
  position: absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
  display:block;
  background:black;
  z-index:-1;
}
canvas#spiders {
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenLite.min.js"></script><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<i></i>
<canvas id="spiders" class="hidden-xs" width="1280" height="451"></canvas>
```